# Is there any place in Israel where you can enjoy walking in huge forests/parks?

Tags: israel, nature-and-wildlife

Is there any place in Israel where you can enjoy walking in huge forests/parks?

And there are some more wishes (not compulsory, but very expected):

- it should be by the sea
- it should be cheap to visit
- it should be in walking distance from city where you can find hotels, restaraunts (or take a city bus to get there)

I hope you to share your real travelling experience or this is your homeland

Comment: Huge and Israel don't compute together, unless you're a fan of the desert...

Comment: Have you at least tried with Google? 'cause at least just the first few thousands results answer your question...

Comment: @JonathanReez, "huge" with respect to Israel. I meant not only ten trees, but at least a place where you can feel you are not in the city, you are outdoors.

Comment: @motoDrizzt, I hope there is someone who have already traveled at such places or lives there (travel.stackexchenge is the fast way to get verified information)

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko ok, that's understandable. But many of the answers in this case could be "I'll google it for you, then post an answer" ;-) If you are asking for first hand, confirmed experiences, you should explicit it in the question body ;-)

Comment: Yoy need to be more specific. What do you mean by huge, by park and by travel. The biggest walk is the Israel trail which goes from the north of Israel to its south and takes anywhere between 2 month to infinity to finish entirely. It also has parts by the sea and inside cities. There are also several parks by the sea in several different cities.

Comment: @SIMEL, JonathanReez understood me the right way, just a single place not a trail (that contains desert parts, roads etc.). That is why I stated "not far from city", so I could live in the city and spend some time in the forest/park

Answer (score 4):

From your description the only place that comes close is the [Carmel Mountain National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Carmel_National_Park) in Haifa:

- You can see the sea from the park
- It's free to visit
- It's surrounded by city streets so you can take a regular city bus to get there

Source: living in Haifa and other Israeli cities.